# How to fix Alamofire library errors?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire, xcode7.3

I am using Xcode7.3.1 and i added  Alamofire (4.0.1) version.But when i tried to run the project then i got many errors in Alamofire library.Please find attached screenshot contains errors.My podfile contain like the following.How to fix these errors?

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'ALamoWeather' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  # Pods for ALamoWeather
pod 'Alamofire'
end
```

[image]

Comment: Version 4.x is for Swift 3.

Comment: Alamofire 4.x is not supported in xcode 7.x. If you want to use it than update xcode to 8.x and use swift 3.0. Swift 3.0 is also not supported in xcode 7.x. @Jasper

Comment: If you are using Xcode7.3, then use lower version of Alamofire version, like 3.5.0 OR update to Xcode8. Any-point you would have to upgrade the code to swift 3.0 anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alamofire 4.0.1 is using Swift 3, while Xcode 7.x doesn't support it. You should upgrade to Xcode 8 in order to use the newest Alamofire.

Comment: I changed the podfile like   pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4.1' . Now its working fine in xcode 7.3.1. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, that's the way to go if you don't want to switch to Swift 3 for any reasons.